# Bootstrap Vertical Menu dropdown highlights NEXT menu item but not sub menus of CURRENT PARENT

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

all...

So here's my BOOTSTRAP code for a vertical DROP DOWN side bar menu:

```
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-nav">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#slider">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown" id="dropdown1">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown1" role="button">Projects <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#dev">In Development</a></li>
                            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#preprod">Pre-Production</a></li>
                            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#prod">Production</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#showcase">Showcase</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#team">Dream Team</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown" id="dropdown2">
                        <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown2" role="button">My<br>Entertainment <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#gloprojects">Projects</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="funcs.btnFunc('privacy', '10', 'null', 'null')">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="funcs.btnFunc('terms', '9', 'null', 'null')">Terms of Use</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

So here are the images which best displays what's occurring:

[image]

Then when you hover on SUB MENU, the NEXT MENU is highlighted...

[image]

This is very confusing...

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My post following up to see if you had figured this out was deleted, but wanted to come back and post the answer I figured out in case it helps someone else.

Using your code as an example, I added a class to the submenu items and then used CSS to set position: unset.

```
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="top-nav">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#slider">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">About Us</a></li>
                <li class="**submenu** dropdown" id="dropdown1">
                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown1" role="button">Projects <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#dev">In Development</a></li>
                        <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#preprod">Pre-Production</a></li>
                        <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#prod">Production</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#showcase">Showcase</a></li>
                <li><a href="#team">Dream Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown" id="dropdown2">
                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown2" role="button">My<br>Entertainment <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="page-scroll"><a href="#gloprojects">Projects</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="funcs.btnFunc('privacy', '10', 'null', 'null')">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" onclick="funcs.btnFunc('terms', '9', 'null', 'null')">Terms of Use</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {
/* only setting when mobile menu in effect */
    .submenu {
        position: unset;
    }
}
```

I'm sure I'm breaking something somewhere, but I haven't come across it yet in my testing. But it does get the desired result, so I'm moving forward with it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).